# Amazon s3 storage - image not rendering on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use amazon s3 to host the image associated to pins on my app.
But its not rendering even if the image are correctly uploaded on amazon.
I got this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<script/>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<RequestId>F74AE7FB3C0DAAE1</RequestId>
<Bucket>sharkit</Bucket>
<HostId>
3bMgNOzRuefbVDmcDL2zV1MStlmML/5tSVKof82afYv8sC5ALsJGW+l2EFRHCyFJ
</HostId>
<Endpoint>sharkit.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
</Error>
```

The thing is that the images are uploaded correctly to my bucket.

I granted all the correct permissions on my bucket so I am out of ideas what it could be...

**UPDATE (solution):**

I got it working by setting a new bucket to US standard instead of US Oregon. I don't really know why, but it works.

Comment: Are you using Paperclip to upload the images to your S3 bucket? If so, how are your `paperclip_defaults` set up? Please post the defaults **without** your aws actual credentials like `access_key_id`.

Comment: Sorry - I got it fixed by setting my bucket to US STANDARD instead of US WEST - OREGON ! thanks for your time btw.